# why all testcases not getting reported to xray

Tags: selenium, jenkins, devops, jira-xray

i am triggering my test from jenkins
Total Tests: 393 (±0)
Failed Configurations: 0 (±0)
Failed Tests: 18 (±0)

but in Xray cloud - TOTAL TESTS: 60     PASSED- 46 ,  FAILED-14 for entire regression...

My TestNG Report.xml-https://pastebin.com/xV671g4F

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is because you are doing data-driven testing and several test methods are executed plenty of times.
You can try searching for the Test issue that corresponds to GETSubjectForAuthTeacher", and look at execution details to see the Test Run information. Probably inside of it, you'll see 68 entries/inner results.

```
$ fgrep '<test-method' ~/Downloads/xV671g4F.txt |  egrep -o 'name="\w+"' | uniq -c
   1 name="GETCountryForAuthTeacher"
   1 name="GETCountryForGuestTeacher"
   1 name="GETCountryForAuthStudent"
   1 name="GETCountryForGuestStudent"
   8 name="GETGradeForAuthTeacher"
   8 name="GETGradeForAuthStudent"
   8 name="GETGradeForGuestStudent"
   8 name="GETDegreeForAuthTeacher"
   1 name="GETDegreeforGuestTeacher"
   1 name="GETDegreeforTeacherNegative"
   8 name="GETDegreeForAuthStudent"
   8 name="GETDegreeforGuestStudent"
   1 name="GETDegreeforStudentNegative"
   3 name="GETMajorForAuthTeacher"
   1 name="GETMajorforGuestTeacher"
   1 name="GETMajorforTeacherNegative"
   3 name="GETMajorForAuthStudent"
   3 name="GETMajorforGuestStudent"
   1 name="GETMajorforStudentNegative"
  88 name="GETSubjectForAuthTeacher"
   8 name="GETCurriculumForAuthTeacher"
   8 name="GETK12ChaptersForAuthTeacher"
   5 name="GETSkillChaptersForAuthTeacher"
   2 name="GETTestPrepChaptersForAuthTeacher"
   3 name="GETUniversityChaptersForAuthTeacher"
   2 name="GETK12TestsForAuthTeacher"
   2 name="GETUniversityTestsForAuthTeacher"
   2 name="GETK12SectionsForAuthTeacher"
   2 name="GETUniversitySectionsForAuthTeacher"
   6 name="GETK12SkillForAuthTeacher"
   1 name="GETK12SkillNegativeForTeacher"
   1 name="GETSkillForGuestTeacher"
   4 name="GETK12SkillTopicsForAuthTeacher"
   2 name="GETK12TestPrepTopicsForAuthTeacher"
   8 name="GETK12TopicsForAuthTeacher"
   4 name="GETCoursesForAuthTeacher"
   1 name="GETCountryForAuthAdmin"
   1 name="GETCountryForGuestAdmin"
   8 name="GETGradeForAuthAdmin"
   8 name="GETDegreeForAuthAdmin"
   1 name="GETDegreeforAdminNegative"
   1 name="GETDegreeforGuestAdmin"
   3 name="GETMajorForAuthAdmin"
   1 name="GETMajorforAdminNegative"
   1 name="GETMajorforGuestAdmin"
  88 name="GETSubjectForAuthAdmin"
   8 name="GETCurriculumForAuthAdmin"
   8 name="GETK12ChaptersForAuthAdmin"
   5 name="GETSkillChaptersForAuthAdmin"
   2 name="GETTestPrepChaptersForAuthAdmin"
   3 name="GETUniversityChaptersForAuthAdmin"
   2 name="GETK12TestsForAuthAdmin"
   1 name="GETUniversityTestsForAuthAdmin"
   2 name="GETK12SectionForAuthAdmin"
   2 name="GETUniversitySectionForAuthAdmin"
   6 name="GETK12SkillForAuthAdmin"
   1 name="GETK12SkillNegativeForAdmin"
   1 name="GETSkillForGuestAdmin"
   4 name="GETK12SkillTopicsForAuthAdmin"
   2 name="GETK12TestPrepTopicsForAuthAdmin"
   8 name="GETK12TopicsForAuthAdmin"
   4 name="GETCoursesForAuthAdmin"
   1 name="SearchCurriculumTagForAuthAdmin"
   1 name="SearchGradeTagForAuthAdmin"
   1 name="SearchSubjectTagForAuthAdmin"
   1 name="GETCurriculumTagForAuthAdmin"
   1 name="GETGradeForAuthAdmin"
   1 name="GETSubjectTagForAuthAdmin"
```

Comment: how to display all methods then 393

Comment: sorry, I didnt understand your question? can you please rephrase?

Comment: how to show 393 testcases report in xray jira

Comment: As I explained in my answer, you can't due to the reason I've mentioned: data-driven tests will be mapped to the same Test issue and the corresponding Test Run will embrace the results for all the iterations of the corresponding data.